# Haskell: define interpreter for language

Tags: haskell, interpreter

As part of defining a language interpreter I have the following definition:

```
initCtx :: Context
initCtx = (Map.empty, initEnv)
  where initEnv =
          Map.fromList [ ...
                       , ("+", undefined)
                         ...
                       ]
```

And for the sum operation I have this:

```
evalExpr :: Expr -> Interpreter Value
evalExpr (e1 :+: e2) = do v1 <- eval e1
                      v2 <- eval e2
                      return Interpreter $ (v1 + v2)
```

The exalExpr is made by me, but what do I need to write in place of `undefined` so that the expression is executed? Or, perhaps, I am looking to the wrong thing ? I have more operations of course, but I just need to have an example. I am veeeeery new to Haskell, I am practically required to deal with it.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

```
type Env = Map Ident Value
type Primitive = [Value] -> Interpreter Value
type PEnv = Map FunName Primitive
type Context = (Env, PEnv)
```

Here's `Expr`:

```
data Expr = Number Int
          | String String
          | Array [Expr]
          | Undefined
          | TrueConst
          | FalseConst
          | Var Ident
          | Compr ArrayFor Expr
          | Call FunName [Expr]
          | Assign Ident Expr
          | Comma Expr Expr
          deriving (Eq, Read, Show)
```

And `Interpreter`

```
newtype Interpreter a = Interpreter {runInterpreter :: Context -> Either Error (a, Env)}
```

And Value:

```
data Value = IntVal Int
           | UndefinedVal
           | TrueVal | FalseVal
           | StringVal String
           | ArrayVal [Value]
           deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Comment: Is this an exercise where you've been given A, B, C and told to go implement X, Y, Z? Or are you designing the whole thing yourself?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid it's an exercise, yes

Comment: Can you tell us specifically which bits you've been given and what they're supposed to mean? (E.g., it looks like `Context` is a pair of maps — but what are those maps supposed to *mean*? Where does `:+:` come from?)

Comment: In fairness, "write an interpreter" would be a major undertaking in C# or Java. But in Haskell it's a small beginner's exercise. Maybe *that* is why people think Haskell is a "hard language". ;-)

Comment: If `(+)` is in the environment, you probably need to define `evalExpr (e1 :+: e2)` not using the Haskell `+` but fetching the meaning of `+` from the environment. So, something like `Intepreter $ \ctx -> let plus = lookupEnv ctx "+" in ...` for some custom `lookupEnv`. You also need to add functions to your values.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I'll take a stab at this...

So it looks like a `Context` consists of a pair of maps. It appears the first map lets you look up a variable's value from its name. The second one lets you look up a function name and get the corresponding executable code for it.

You're using `Interpreter` as if it's a monad; I don't know whether it actually is, but it looks plausible.

So `initCtx` starts off with no variables defined (`Map.empty`), and presumably you're meant to put a bunch of predefined functions like `+` in the second map.

Looking at the definition for `Primitive`, it takes a list of `Value` and returns an `Interpreter` computation. So I guess it looks something like

```
addExpr :: [Value] -> Interpreter Value
addExpr [e1, e2] = do
  v1 <- eval e1
  v2 <- eval e2
  return (v1 + v2)
```

and then you could write `map.fromList [... ("+", addExpr) ...]`.

Except that's not quite right either. `Value` isn't a number type; what happens if, say, `v1 = StringVal`? For that matter, what if somebody calls "+" with a different number of arguments? We need some error checking here.

I'm *guessing* the thing you're looking for probably looks something like this:

```
checkInt :: Value -> Interpreter Int
checkInt (IntVal x) = return x
checkInt _          = Interpreter $ ctx -> Left "Not an integer."

addExpr :: [Value] -> Interpreter Value
addExpr [expr1, expr2] do
  val1 <- eval expr1
  int1 <- checkInt val1

  val2 <- eval expr2
  int2 <- checkInt val2

  return (IntVal $ int1 + int2)
addExpr _ = Interpreter $ ctx -> error "Wrong number of arguments."
```